# NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android

Разрабатываю приложение под андроид. Для тестов использую девайс на андроид 5.0.1 (SGS IV), работает нормально. Попробовал Запустить на 4.1 (SGS III mini) и на запуске основной активити словил ошибку, судя по стектрейсу - связанную с `inflate` моих `View`. Подскажите, что могло её вызвать. Все библиотеки, классы и методы, использованные в проекте совместимы с API 16, поэтому я не думаю, что дело в этом.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
  ComponentInfo{com.market.lavkalavka/com.lavkalavka.pages.root.DrawerActivityNew}:
  android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15:
  Error inflating class com.widget.lavkaviews.Header
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15:
   Error inflating class com.widget.lavkaviews.Header
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901)
    at com.lavkalavka.pages.root.DrawerActivityNew.onCreate(DrawerActivityNew.java:48)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901) 
    at com.lavkalavka.pages.root.DrawerActivityNew.onCreate(DrawerActivityNew.java:48) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15:
   Error inflating class com.widget.lavkaviews.Text
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:613)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at com.widget.lavkaviews.Header.<init>(Header.java:58)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901) 
    at com.lavkalavka.pages.root.DrawerActivityNew.onCreate(DrawerActivityNew.java:48) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at com.widget.lavkaviews.Header.<init>(Header.java:58) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901) 
    at com.lavkalavka.pages.root.DrawerActivityNew.onCreate(DrawerActivityNew.java:48) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.widget.assets.font
    at com.widget.lavkaviews.Text.<init>(Text.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at com.widget.lavkaviews.Header.<init>(Header.java:58) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:316) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1901) 
    at com.lavkalavka.pages.root.DrawerActivityNew.onCreate(DrawerActivityNew.java:48) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Ошибка тут: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.widget.assets.font  at com.widget.lavkaviews.Text.<init>(Text.java:25)` соответствеено расскажите в вопросе что это за класс и приведите его 25 строку. Похоже, там какие-то манипуляции со шрифтами.

Comment: Приведу дословно, у меня запутанная на первый взгляд иерархия, Text это наследник TextView, с измененным Typeface. В остальном это TextView с парой нужных мне методов. В 25 строке происходит определение Typeface (сама строка находится в конструкторе), строка setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(App.assetManager, "fonts/couriernew.ttf"))

Comment: Попробуйте убрать строку эту. Если поможет - выясняйте из-за чего крах. Если таки в шрифтах из ассетов - то я тут помочь не смогу. Но вы можете переформулировать заголовок, вопрос, добавить инфы и получить ответ от кого-то другого.

Comment: лучше весь код покажите

Answer (score 2):

`NoClassDefFoundError` - Эта ошибка возникает, если данный класс не был найден.
В вашем случае это вполне возможно, т.к. вы работали на более новой версии, а старой версии такая ошибка выскакивает, т.к. там банально не добавлено новое API, поэтому и такая ошибка, [Support Library](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/index.html).

Ошибка в подключении класса  `com.widget.lavkaviews.Header`

Если `com.widget.lavkaviews.Header` это ваш кастомный `View`, то посмотрите, не было ли добавлено аннотаций отвечающих за версии API

Comment: Сейчас эту ошибку вызывают другие классы, а именно хранящие статические поля, которые используются как флаги итд. И в логе я вижу так же в большом количестве сообщения типа  I/dalvikvm: DexOpt: unable to optimize static field ref 0x5f64 at 0xa1